# In what ways can I verify the uniqueness of the solution of this PDE system

Tags: partial-differential-equations

In what ways can I verify a uniqueness of the solution to the following problem
$$ \begin{array}{ c @{{}{}} r  >{{}}c<{{}} r  >{{}}c<{{}}  l }
 u_{tt}+u_{xxxx}+\theta_{xx}=0 & \quad x\in(0,L)\times \mathbb{R}^{+}\\
 \theta_{t}-\theta_{xx}-u_{xxt}=0  &\quad x\in(0,L)\times \mathbb{R}^{+}\\
u(0,t)=u(L,t)=u_{x}(0,t)=u_{x}(L,t)=0  & \quad t >0 \\
 \theta(0,t)=\theta(L,t)=0
 \end{array}
$$

assuming that $(u, \theta) $ and $ (\hat{u}, \hat{\theta}) $ are solutions quite regular, define $\phi = u - \hat{u} $ and $\psi = \theta - \hat{\theta}$.Then $(\phi, \psi)$ is the solution of the problem, Then I tried to arrive at an energy equation by multiplying the first line of the system by $\phi_t$ and the second by $\psi$

$$  \dfrac{1}{2}\dfrac{d}{dt}\left(||{\psi}_{t}||_2^2  +||\phi||_2^2+||\psi_{xx}||_2^2\right)+||\psi_{x}||_2^{2}=0
$$
then I integrated and I arrive that the norms $||{\psi}_{t}||_2^2  +||\phi||_2^2+||\psi_{xx}||_2^2$ are less than or equal to zero.
Is it wrong that way? Is there another way to demonstrate this uniqueness? Besides, if the solutions are not regular, what to do?